# Rename files using folder name as prefix

Tags: r, rename

I have several pdf files which I want to rename with the prefix of the folder. How can I rename the pdf files with the name of the folder that follows "RS" in the data structure shown below?. I have searched this forum for previous posts and found some examples but every question was unique  I could not adopt to my situation.

Current data structure:

```
C:\Users\KG\Downloads\RS\pulmonary\chapter1\1 a.pdf
C:\Users\KG\Downloads\RS\pulmonary\chapter1\1 b.pdf
C:\Users\KG\Downloads\RS\pulmonary\chapter2\2 a.pdf
C:\Users\KG\Downloads\RS\pulmonary\chapter2\2 b.pdf
C:\Users\KG\Downloads\RS\endocrine\1 b.pdf 
C:\Users\KG\Downloads\RS\endocrine\1 a.pdf
```

Intended result:

```
pulmonary1 a.pdf
pulmonary1 b.pdf
pulmonary2 a.pdf
pulmonary2 b.pdf
endocrine1 b.pdf
endocrine1 a.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is your vector of file paths, the regular expression below returns the file names in your example.

```
new.x = gsub(".*\\RS\\([a-z]*)\\(.*\\)?([0-9].*)", "\\1\\3", x)
```

If you can have, say, "Chapter" instead of only "chapter", or if the numbers after "chapter" or in the file name can be two or more digits, then the regex would need a few tweaks to make it more general.